# Why can I find the ribbon visible in the home tab, but not in Excel options > customize ribbon

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

The need to change this particular group under the home tab, and so I go into Excel options to find it, but it somehow doesn't show this group. There is some VBA written behind these options, but I need to see them in Excel options window

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Because you are looking in the wrong place. Judging by the signature on the Ribbon, this  ribbon-group change that made the add-in. Look for it in File-Options-Add-ins - Active

Comment: Thank you for the response . I'm sorry  but it says there are no active Add-ins in the application

Comment: You are looking for a "PE 111500" group - don't look under the "home" part...

Answer (score 1):

Since I am new to SO, I currently cannot comment and can only post this comment as an answer (sorry!). You will not find the group "PE 111500" under the options > customized ribbon or through the addin. Like you mentioned, that part of the ribbon is created through VBA code. In order to rename the group, add to the group, delete buttons from the group, or delete the whole group entirely, you will need to find it in the modules within the VBA code. I have done something like this before for work and it should be easily found. If you don't mind sharing the workbook, I can take a look at it and provide you with a solution.